# Holding an static StringBuilder

Tags: java, android

We are looking to have a String builder that holds references to some events in the device,

We considered to write and read a file but the cost of opening and closing a file every time we write to it seems too high.

The issue is that sometimes we are getting a StackOverflow exception even if we try to keep the StringBuilder for just a defined size

```
public class DiagnosticUtil {

private static final int  DIAGNOSTIC_SIZE = 5000;

public static StringBuilder DIAGNOSTICS_HOLDER = new StringBuilder(DIAGNOSTIC_SIZE);

public static void addDiagnosticLine(String message){
    try {
        //Limits the size of the diagnostics recolection removing the first 2000 characters
        if (DiagnosticUtil.DIAGNOSTICS_HOLDER.length() > DIAGNOSTIC_SIZE - 300) {
            DiagnosticUtil.DIAGNOSTICS_HOLDER.delete(0, DiagnosticUtil.DIAGNOSTICS_HOLDER.length() - 2000);
        }
        DIAGNOSTICS_HOLDER.append(TimeUtils.getCurrentDate()).append(message).append("\n");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Timber.d("Error saving additional data");
    }

}
```

}

The question is, Is this a good approach? Or should we save this logs to an external file?.

Thanks!

Comment: `StringBuilder` doesn't hold references to anything, let alone events. Are you looking for a `Collection` of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create StringBuilder with preferred size you consume memory, because internally in StringBuilder created char[] array with this size before you pass any String to it, so you need to use default constructor there. Why do you decide to use Builder there instead of List? I don't see all picture but i think you may be prefer to choose something different with two approaches (memory log and file log store) When you collect certain amount of messages simple write it to file, in this way you don't need to touch filesystem for every message and don't populate memory with that amount of log data. You need code something like this:

```
public class DiagnosticUtil {
    private final static int threshold = 1000;
    private static List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final File log = new File("path to your file");

    public static void addDiagnosticLine(String message) {
        if (messages.size() > threshold) {
            try (BufferedWriter file = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log))) {
                for (String msg : messages) {
                    file.write(msg);
                }
                file.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Timber.d("Error saving additional data " + e);
            }
            messages = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            messages.add(TimeUtils.getCurrentDate() + message + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

pay attention this is procedural code, not oop, util classes are bad